# bootstrap carousel jump how to find height but not fixed

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap carousel, but I notice a jump when next slide show.

Since I want this to responsive, I can't really set a fixed height.

```
var $carousel_height = $('#myCarousel .item img').outerHeight();
var $carousel_height2 = $('#myCarousel .item img').css("height");
console.log($carousel_height );     
console.log($carousel_height2 );

$('#myCarousel').css('height', $carousel_height2);//apply
```

I kind of use the above codes, but both give me 0px, I believe because I set the width to 100% for the image tag.

So is there a way to set the height to equal to the first slide height?
or any other way to not get the jump?

Thanks,